# Verify link in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hyperlink, email-verification

I need a solution for Gmail verification (When the link is clicked, the app should be able to capture it) in flutter.

When the user signs up it will send a link to the email and when the user clicks it, it will redirect it to the app.

Comment: Take a look at deep links https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.